# How to detect specific parts of a tuple?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Working on a homework question which requires me to make a program which takes a set of tuple and detects if it counts as a domino cycle. For example, if given the tuples `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]`, the program would return `True`. If an example like `[(1,2),(3,4),(7,6)]` is given it would return `False`. Also if only one set of tuple is given but both values within it is the same, for example `[(5,5)]`, `True` should be returned otherwise `False`, for example `[(2,3)]`. this is the part which I'm having issues with is getting the program to detect when a single tuple is given and wether the values inside it are the same. Also there are empty domino pieces in the game as well, I want the program to return True if an empty list is given such as "[]".

This is what I have so far and it just returns `None` when I try to run it for a single pair tuple. For multiple pairs of tuples, it works.

```
def cycle(tiles):
    for i in range(len(tiles)-1):
        tile1 = tiles[i]
        tile2 = tiles [i+1]

        if tile1[1:] == tile2[0:1] or ((tile1 and not tile2) or (not tile1 and not tile2)):
            return True
        else:
            return False

print (cycle([(4,4)]))
```

Comment: Hint: How long is the `range` when `len(tiles) == 1`? What should you do if `len(tiles) == 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't account for one tile case

```
def cycle(tiles):
    if len(tiles) == 0:
        return True
    if len(tiles) == 1:
        return tiles[0][0] == tiles [0][1]
    for i in range(len(tiles)-1):
        if  tiles[i][1] != tiles[i+1][0]:
            return False
    return True
print (cycle([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])) #True
print (cycle([(1,2),(5,3),(3,4)])) #False
print (cycle([(4,4)])) # True
print((cycle([(1,2),(2,3),(4,4)]))) #False
```

Comment: Don't `return True`, `return tiles[0][0] == tiles[0][1]`

Comment: Yes that works too, but I try not to change to the original code as much, returning true for someone beginning is kinda easier to understand

Comment: I mean `if len(tiles) < 2: return True` is wrong when `tiles = [(2, 3)]`

Comment: Of I thought you're talking about syntax wise, I'm not too sure about the game rule, I thought if there's only one that counts as True

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for the reply, the question also says that when given an empty list such as [], the program should still return True. Any suggestions on what to do in this case? when I try putting in an empty list right now, it gives an error: list index out of range

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for the reply, the question also says that when given an empty list such as [] since there are empty domino pieces, the program should still return True. Any suggestions on what to do in this case? when I try putting in an empty list right now, it gives an error: list index out of range

Comment: There's no way passing en empty list will raise that error since it will never reach the loop, if the list empty or has one tile it will return true automatically, how did you call the function?

Comment: I just added the part if len(tiles) < 2: return (tiles[0][0]== tiles[0][1])  in to my code.

Comment: You can try the code I edited, should work, you need to account for the empty list separate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202664/discussion-between-farhan-iqbal-and-marsilinou-zaky).

Comment: @MarsilinouZaky Thank you, It seems that the code only works for the first 2 set of tuples in any given scenario. For example    (cycle([(1,2),(2,3),(4,4)])), this would still print out True even though the last pair does not meet the requirement. I tried to put this condition in if tile1[1:] != tile2[0:1]: return False, but the code still does not work. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I just updated the answer, your logic wasn't correct, you didn't get to loop through the whole list, it would return the answer based on only the first tile, if that works go ahead and pick best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If time is not a factor, run two for loops to test for domino:

```
In [1]: m = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]

In [2]: n = [(1,2),(3,4),(7,6)]

In [3]: all([i[1] == j[0] for i, j in zip(m[:-1], m[1:])])
Out[3]: True

In [4]: all([i[1] == j[0] for i, j in zip(n[:-1], n[1:])])
Out[4]: False
```

So the function should be:

```
def cycle(M):
    if not M:
        return True #will return True for empty list
    if len(M) == 1:
        return M[0] == M[1]
    return all(i[1] == j[0] for i, j in zip(M[:-1], M[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dominoes=[(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)]
def isdomino(agg, item):
   #print(agg, item)
   if agg[0] == 1:
      if item[0] == item[1]:
         return 'True', ''
      else:
         return 'False', ''
   else:  
     if agg[0] == 'False':
       return 'False', ''
     if agg[1] == item[0]:
       return 'True', item[1]
     return 'False', item[1]

def checkdominoes(dominoes):
   if len(dominoes) == 0:
     return ('True', '')
   else:
     return reduce(isdomino, dominoes, (len(dominoes),dominoes[0][0]))


dominoes=[(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)]
something = checkdominoes(dominoes)
eval(something[0])
# False

dominoes=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)]
something = checkdominoes(dominoes)
eval(something[0])
# True

dominoes=[(1,2)]
something = checkdominoes(dominoes)
eval(something[0])
# False

dominoes=[(2,2)]
something = checkdominoes(dominoes)
eval(something[0])
# True

dominoes=[]
something = checkdominoes(dominoes)
eval(something[0])
# True
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the question but since there are empty domino pieces in the game, how can I get an output of True if an empty list is put in such as []

Comment: I updated it for that case at the end, does that work?